# Python and Plone help

Tags: python, plone, nameerror

Im using the plone cms and am having trouble with a python script. I get a name error "the global name 'open' is not defined". When i put the code in a seperate python script it works fine and the information is being passed to the python script becuase i can print the query. Code is below:

```
#Import a standard function, and get the HTML request and response objects.
from Products.PythonScripts.standard import html_quote
request = container.REQUEST
RESPONSE = request.RESPONSE



# Insert data that was passed from the form
query=request.query
#print query


f = open("blast_query.txt","w")
for i in query:
    f.write(i)

return printed
```

I also have a second question, can i tell python to open a file in in a certain directory for example, If the script is in a certain loaction i.e. home folder, but i want the script to open a file at home/some_directory/some_directory can it be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python Scripts in Plone are restricted and have no access to the filesystem. The open call is thus not available. You'll have to use an External Method or full python module to have full access to the filesystem.

Comment: Exactly. You can check this link from Plone for more information: http://plone.org/documentation/faq/restricted-python-scripts

Comment: Just read up on the external methods, could you elaborate of the full python module?